modify style for a paragraph in PhpOffice\PhpWord
How to use modify style for a paragraph in phpword. I want the part of the paragraph that is Latin to get a separate font, the rest of the paragraph that is not Latin get another font.
I tested this but it didn't work
$phpWord->addFontStyle(
                $fontStyleName,
                ['name' => 'B Nazanin', 'size' => 13, 'bold' => false, 'color' => 'black', 'rtl' => true],
                ['name' => 'Calibri', 'size' => 11, 'bold' => false, 'color' => 'black', 'rtl' => true, 'lang' => 'en-US'],
            );
            $myCell->addText('تست test', $fontStyleName);

